# I'm looking for a word like populated, but related to objects. Such as a folder with many images in it

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word similar to "populated" in meaning, but in respect to objects only. Such as one to define a folder with many images in it.

Comment: Your title and question body are almost same. It's unclear what you are asking for. Please edit your question and add clarification.

Comment: @BiscuitBoy is the context more clear now? if not plz let me know how i may clarify it better.

Comment: Would the word full fit? Like "the folder is  full of images."

Comment: Still not clear to me, especially with " in respect to objects only".  Are you looking for a computer related term?

Comment: Does *concentrated* help? e.g. *a file of high/low image concentration*.

Comment: @BiscuitBoy no. Let me try to put it this was. I want to write that I wish to add another image/toy/book to a folder/box/container that already has several items in it. I don't wish to use the word "full".

Comment: Similar to "A person just walked into an already populated room."

Comment: *Populated* **is** used for data storage structures. In your last example ("walked into an already populated room") *occupied* would work better anyway. Effectively you need an antonym for "empty" - a good thesaurus might help.

Comment: @ChrisH the first bit was helpful. The last bit sounded sarcastic. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You could say that it's *full*, or is *filled*. You could also say that it *contains* things.

You could also say that it's *occupied by images*.

Comment: To me, 'occupied with' implies 'busy with' ("He's occupied with preparing the annual accounts today"). The term to use is 'occupied by' ("The train compartment was occupied by schoolchildren").

Comment: @ErikKowal - That's a good point, thanks. I've amended.

Answer (score 1):

What about **stuffed** that unfortunately has a connotation of excessive filling, but may fit to suggest that the folder has too many images?

> "stuff" definition: to fill a receptacle, especially by packing the
>   contents closely together.
>
> Example: *Also, every nook and cranny that isn't full of spare parts is stuffed with tools or emergency equipment*.

Note that "populate" also refers to objects, specially in computer science where the expression "populate a database/datatable" is often used.